# Inicializar una datatable sin saber las columnas

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

¿Cómo puedo inicializar una datatable a partir de un array json del que desconozco cuantas columnas tiene?

```
json = '[["DAT","XXXXXX","000000000","MA_","","21-07-2015","00:04:43","0","354345","94131","Datos","0.00000000"],  ["DAT","XXXXXX","000000000","MA_","","21-07-2015","00:04:43","0","354345","94131","Datos","0.00000000"]]';

json = JSON.parse(json)
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data:json ,
    columns: [
        { title: 'dato' },
        { title: 'dato' },
        { title: 'dato' },
        { title: 'dato' },
        { title: 'dato' },
        { title: 'dato' },
        { title: 'dato' },
        { title: 'dato' }, 
    ]
});
```

Lo que busco es declarar la datatable sin tener que usar la opción **columns** ya que desconozco cuantas columnas se le van a pasar

[Ejemplo](http://live.datatables.net/gahezaco/4/edit?js,output)

Comment: Y ya probaste qué pasa omitiendo el parámetro columns?

Comment: Si, y no funciona. Puedes probarlo en el enlace del ejemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo aprovechara esa variable json y crearia columnasdinamicamente con `Array(<number>)`

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    json = '[["DAT","XXXXXX","000000000","MA_","","21-07-2015","00:04:43","0","354345","94131","Datos","0.00000000"],["DAT","XXXXXX","000000000","MA_","","21-07-2015","00:04:43","0","354345","94131","Datos","0.00000000"]]';
    json = JSON.parse(json);
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        data:json,
        columns: json.length > 0 ? Array(json[0].length).fill({title: ''}) : []
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Se usa 'columnDefs' para tal fin. Consulta la referencia en [datatables.net](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs)

```
json = JSON.parse(json)
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    data:json,
    "columnDefs": [ {
        "targets": -1,
        "data": null,
        "defaultContent": "dato"
    } ]
});
```

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y no funciona, me sigue diciendo que las columnas nos están definidas. [Ejemplo](http://live.datatables.net/gahezaco/3/edit?js,output)